# Generating Excel Report Using Php

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate Excel report of Employee Schedule Times in a week.

I have one function which calculate total hours and mins in a week and will return in format
`Hours:Mins.`

I am displaying total hours in excel. The issue here is after 24:00 total time i.e if the total time is 25:00 it is printing in Excel as 25:00:00.

I want it to be 25:00 instead. I don't understand the issue.

Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: Which Excel framework library are you using?

Comment: And what number format masking ar eyou applying to that calculated cell?

Comment: header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=EMP_ScheduleReport_excel.xls");

Comment: i am using Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: headers and content type don't automagically create an excel file.... how are you generating the actual excel data that you send to the browser to go with those headers

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating the excel file? Is it just a csv/tab delimited? If so then no date formatting is applied to the cells, which is the problem.

If you want to apply date formats etc. to cells using PHP, I would suggest using something like the PHPExcel library.

Comment: i am creating by using Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel.

Comment: can you post the exact code you are using to create the excel file?